# TinyMCE - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jinja2

The following HTML is rendered using Jinja2 templating

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("<p>skldjlfjsd kajshdfkhasdlk falsd</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>sdf</p>
<p>sdsdfsd</p>
<p>&nbsp;f</p>
<p>sdfsdfsd</p>");
```

the template is

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("{{ article.content|safe }}");
```

The browser gives me the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the unescaped new line characters in the string passed to `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent`. There are several ways to fix this, and one of them is to put each line in a separate string and concatenate them together like this for example.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent([
    "<p>skldjlfjsd kajshdfkhasdlk falsd</p>",
    "<p>&nbsp;</p>",
    "<p>sdf</p>",
    "<p>sdsdfsd</p>", 
    "<p>&nbsp;f</p>",
    "<p>sdfsdfsd</p>"
].join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I recommend using the `{ format: 'raw' }` in `getContent()` before saving the data.
Something like this, using long_description field as example of tinymce object in my form:

```
form.append("long_desc",tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'raw' }));
...
form.save()
```

To edit the data:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#long_desc",
    ...
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('init', function (e) {
        editor.setContent('{{ product.product_long_description|safe }}');
      });
    }});
```

The basic difference between using or not using  `{ format: 'raw' }` to save the content, especially if the content has an enter key or paragraphs inside, is the way the html data is saved in the database.
Here you can see this difference:

```
//without format raw   
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>

//with format raw
<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
```

Using `{ format: 'raw' }` to save content avoids later problems in `setContent()`, because `setContent()` can't read data with line breaks.